# redirect route for validation in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I have a problem with the redirectRoute property in Laravel. What I want to do is: after the validation of the request, for example, the register request fails, redirect to another view with the proper errors. I have tried with `protected $redirectRoute = '/route-name'` in the RegisterController but it's not working. I'm using Laravel 5.4

Comment: Also it would be helpful to specify which version of Laravel you are using and apply the appropriate tag

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#manually-creating-validators

You'll need to manually create the validator and then you can tell it exactly where to redirect to if the validation fails:

```
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
        'body' => 'required',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect('post/create')
                    ->withErrors($validator)
                    ->withInput();
    }
```

And if you are using Form Requests, you can override the following properties to redirect to a custom location:

```
protected $redirect; // A simple URL. ex: google.com
protected $redirectRoute; // A route name to redirect to.
protected $redirectAction; // A controller action to redirect to.
```

Comment: I've tried the $redirectRoute property, but it doesn't work. I'll try the custom request then. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer, tested in Laravel 8. it is possible to create a ValidationException and set a custom redirect on it.

Summary:

```
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;

$validator->setException( (new ValidationException($validator))->redirectTo('your/custom/location'));
$validator->validate();
```